# Is there any use to the slide bounce/kick move?

Tags: super-mario-64

Is there any use to the 'slide bounce/kick' move, apart from attacking enemies and the lava bounce glitch? This is the move where you press Z + B while moving or not moving.

Comment: Can I please know why I got some downvotes?

Comment: Maybe people think it was under-researched? Which I would disagree with, since I searched "SM64 slide kick" and didn't actually find much useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a casual player, the slide kick isn't much more than a way to attack while running. As a speedrunner/special-runner (e.g. A-button challenge), it's an invaluable part of Mario's movement abilities that lets him bounce in specific ways, cross gaps without jumping, and some other zany tricks.

On the other hand I don't think there is any practical use for the crouching kick aside from existing so the button combination does something.